# Is m2e plugin api published anywhere for extension?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

Does the `m2e` plugin expose its API for other eclipse plugins to extend? I'm writing an eclipse plugin which I want to be able to talk to the `m2e` to trigger adhoc maven builds, create and save maven jobs thru the existing wizards and so on.

The reason `m2e` plugin isn't by itself enough for me is that, I want the aforementioned actions to be performed on files of my choice that `m2e` does not associate itself with, like, XML files, on "running" of which (my plugin will have menus for such needs), I want maven builds to be triggered with options of my choice.

I did see the source code [here](https://github.com/eclipse/m2e-core), but if there's an API that it exposes, it would be easy for me to extend and get things done rather than having to look at the entire `m2e` code to do even the most basic of things. I didn't see anything of that sort, though, so wanted to be sure if there's even one.

Comment: Have you seen [m2e Extension Development](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-extension-development.html)?

Comment: I did see it before, but halfway thru reading it, I felt it wasn't all that helpful and a bit unrelated to what I was expecting to see. I instead took to going thru their source code which was at least helping a bit.